# OnTriggerExit() Doesn't Sees When My Object Is Deleted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Made A Object (Let's say It Cube) Which Deletes Itself In 5 Seconds, It Have A Tag Named Spawned.
I Also Made 2 Animations: "DoorOpen" And "DoorClose".
I Made A Object Play DoorOpen When Cube Touches It.
But When The Object Deletes Itself, It Doesn't Activates OnTriggerExit, Is There Any Other Way Like OnTriggerExit To Play A Animation If Cube Is Deleted?
My Trigger Script -

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorOpenTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator doorAnim = null;

    public bool openTrigger = false;
    // public bool closeTrigger = false;

    public string doorOpen = "DoorOpen";
    public string doorClose = "DoorClose";


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Spawned"))
        {
            if (openTrigger)
            {
                doorAnim.Play(doorOpen, 0, 0.0f);
                //openTrigger = false;
            }
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Spawned"))
        {
            if (openTrigger)
            {
                doorAnim.Play(doorClose, 0, 0.0f);
                //openTrigger = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw I am Just A beginner in Unity

Comment: I think you can use [OnDestroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) (to run code just before your object is deleted)

Comment: No, it doesn't works, as the script is connected to other object not cube. But Thanks :)

Comment: Just to be clear: your `OnTriggerEnter` works as expected. Then you destroy the very same object that triggered it (the `other`) while it is still inside the collider right? This should totally trigger the `OnTriggerExit` to get called .. has your animator any influence on this object (disabling, moving, etc?)

Comment: I found That ```OnTriggerExit``` Works When Any Object Gets Out of its Touch, And Cube Was Deleting Itself, Instead I fixed It with Time (Coroutine To Close Door) To Close Door As I answered Below

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! your code is in `c#`

Comment: Oh sorry for that, I didn't knew it.

Answer (score 1):

The Trigger is working as intended.

OnTriggerExit wont trigger because your object never moves from inside the collider out.

You will have to either move the object out first, or play around with OnTriggerStay to fix the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed It With:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorOpenTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator doorAnim = null;

    public bool openTrigger = false;
    public bool closeTrigger = false;

    public string doorOpen = "DoorOpen";
    public string doorClose = "DoorClose";
    public GameObject player;
    bool button;
    float delay = 0f;
    

    void Update() 
    {

    }
    

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Spawned"))
        {
            if (openTrigger)
            {
                doorAnim.Play(doorOpen, 0, 0.0f);
                openTrigger = false;
                closeTrigger = true;
                delay = player.GetComponent<Spawn>().delay;
                StartCoroutine(Do());
            }

            
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Do()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        doorAnim.Play(doorClose, 0, 0.0f);
        openTrigger = true;
    }

}
```

(delay Is Time Variable In My Spawn Script To Delete The Cube)